# Fallo en Tomcat 9 al querer arrancar desde un archivo .war

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-server

Estoy trabajando con Tomcat 9, cargué el archivo .war en el servidor en la carpeta de webapps.
Pero cuando intento arrancar desde Tomcat Manager, me arroja lo siguiente:

**FALLO - No se pudo arrancar la aplicación en trayectoria de contexto [/AIM]
FALLO - Encontrada excepción [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@12e007be]]**

Y en el status de mi Tomcat.service, arroja lo siguiente:

```
● tomcat9.service - Apache Tomcat 9 Web Application Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-04-25 22:07:44 UTC; 2h 15min ago
       Docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html
    Process: 635 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-update-policy.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 672 (java)
      Tasks: 31 (limit: 1066)
     Memory: 258.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat9.service
             └─672 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties
```

-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.j>

```
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:375)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
Apr 25 22:10:29 levitonaim tomcat9[672]:     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Ya he probado en dejar el .war en la carpeta de webapps, y se supone que debería crear la carpeta con los archivos (según he leído), pero no lo hace.

Todo lo estoy montando en un Ubuntu Server 20.04.
Soy algo nuevo en este tema, espero y puedan ayudarme!
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Revisa directamente el archivo de log `catalina.out` para ver la traza completa de errores; dependiendo de tu configuración puede estar en `/usr/local/tomcat/logs/catalina.out` ó `/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out`

Answer (score 0):

En algun caso tuve un problema similar y era porque la versión de java no era compatible con la versión de tomcat. Necesitaba una versión mas nueva de tomcat. En este caso estas usando tomcat 9 pero no se que versión de java. Podrías revisar que sea compatible tu versión de java:
https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html